# Can we use two header files in two separate .mm files in same project in iPhone

Tags: ios, ios6, header-files

I have a project in which i have used `.mm` file and imported a header file. This works fine.

When i create second .mm file and import a header file in that it gives me linker error. It says:

> 166 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You've included same file in your project twice. It's possible that another library (such as sharekit) included it for you, doublecheck the files sharekit includes and remove one copy of that file and things should compile.

Comment: I have checked,i have not included file twice.Problem is that it allows me to add .mm file and code compiles if i import other viewcontrollers.but when i create second header file and import it in .mm file it gives compilation error.Please help..